# django how to load url but stay on same page

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a sign up button on my home page and when user clicks it, it opens sign-up modal form. The problem is I need to have a URL and view for sign-up form and when I click the button server redirects to signup URL and quits from my home page. How can I prevent this?

--Views.py

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if user_form.is_valid():
        #Create a new user object but avoid saving it yet
        new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
        #Set the chosen password
        new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
        #Save the user object
        new_user.save()
        return redirect('home')
else:
    user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
return render(request,'account/signup.html',{'user_form':user_form})
```

--urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(authentication_form=LoginForm), name='login'),
  path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
  path('signup/', user_views.register, name='signup'),
```

]

--signup.js

```
var signup_form = document.querySelector(".signup-form");

var trigger = document.querySelector(".signup-btn");

var closeBtn = document.querySelector(".close-btn");

function toggleModal(){
  signup_form.classList.toggle("show-signup-form");
 }

function windowOnClick(event) {
  if (event.target == signup_form){
    toggleModal();
  }
}

trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
closeBtn.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

Comment: Redirect to the required page after completing signup.

Answer (score 0):

If want to prevent redirection. Try event.preventDefault() in your click function,